# Yii $this not working in model

Tags: php, object, activerecord, yii

I am fairly new to Yii and I have a small problem, but cannot figure it out. The problem is that when i call in Yii in one of my models (active records) $this->attributes = 'something'; I get error "Property "SiteController.attributes" is not defined."

I have this in controller:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    // Create new clients active record
    $client = new Clients;

    // Check if user send some request
    if (isSet($_POST)){
        switch($_POST["action"]){
            case 'newClient':
                $registered = $client::addClient($_POST);
        }
    }

    // render the view
    $this->render('landing',array(
        // Objects
        'client' => $client,
        // Variables
        'registered' => $registered,
    ));

    return true;
}
```

and this in the model:

```
public function addClient($data){
    // Set data
    $this->attributes = $data["Clients"];
    $this->password = self::generatePassword(6);

    // Proceed
    $this->setScenario('insert');

    return true;
}
```

The functions are not complete of course but this is where i get the error. What is it exactly I'm doing wrong? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the function as static method.

`$registered = $client::addClient($_POST);`

should be

```
$registered = $client->addClient($_POST);
```

Answer (score 0):

When stuff like that happens to me I var_dump().  Maybe *this* is not the *this* you think it is.

Otherwise I'd suggest checking the Yii generated code.  Hardly familiar with that framework but check that you or your IDE didn't goof up any of the C-style comments.  Check for typos, code, meta, table.  Also check and make sure you don't already have an entity with the same name, `SiteController` sounds a little generic.